# how to upload csv file which is created using php?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I had write this code but it only generate **csv file** but not upload in directory.

```
$file = 'export';
    $csv_output .= "CustID,CustName,CustMobile,CustEmail\n";

$sql = "select CustID,CustName,CustMobile,CustEmail from dep_customer_details LIMIT 0,10";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
 for ($j=0;$j<$res;$j++) {
  $csv_output .= $row[$j].", ";
 }
 $csv_output .= "\n";
}

$filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header("Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
print $csv_output;


$uploaddir = dirname(__FILE__) .'/csv/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.$filename;
move_uploaded_file($filename,$uploadfile);
```

Comment: move these lines header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header("Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
print $csv_output;
below move_uploaded_file($filename,$uploadfile); and see it should work

Comment: As the file hasn't been uploaded from a web browser but is being generated by your script on the server, what do you expect move_uploaded_file() to actually do? Do you just want to save the file on the server?

Comment: csv generate perfectly but problem in uploading in directory

Comment: @MarkBaker i want to store this csv and send it via email

Comment: So instead of setting the headers to download the file, and trying to use move_uploaded_file(), just use `file_put_contents($uploadfile,$csv_output);`

Comment: @chetan Make it an attachment via the `mail()` function. However the file will need to first be "saved" on your server in order to do that. It needs an actual file and not a memory server-generated file, because those are only temporary made from the server's memory and deleted afterwards.

Comment: in mail its ok but i had more option to send this csv. i also have to send this csv to dropbox. problem is that, dropbox api only choose path so is there any way to store this file to the server?

Comment: @chetan Which server, yours or DropBox?

Comment: @chetan You can try what Satya said in the [first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874200/how-to-upload-csv-file-which-is-created-using-php#comment27853804_18874200). However what Mark Baker mentioned also makes perfect sense in both of his comments. You need to create the file first, then you can do pretty much anything from there afterwards. `move_uploaded_file` needs a form in order for it to work.

Comment: @chetan I came up with a quick script that will create a file with `export_2013-09-18_10-41.csv` as a filename example which saves it inside a sub-folder called `csv`. However this is only an example using Mark Baker's comment `file_put_contents($uploadfile,$csv_output);` and not using headers. That can be implemented afterwards as an attachment. You will need to find a function for it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will create a file with `export_2013-09-18_10-41.csv` for example (as per time of execution on my end) 
which saves it inside a sub-folder called `csv`.

However this is only an example using Mark Baker's comment `file_put_contents($uploadfile,$csv_output);` and not using headers.

That can be implemented afterwards as an attachment. You will need to find a function for it yourself.

```
<?php

$file = 'export';
$csv_output = "CustID,CustName,CustMobile,CustEmail\n";

// Commented out your DB code for you to test 
// my example with above $csv_output fields only.
/*
$sql = "select CustID,CustName,CustMobile,CustEmail from dep_customer_details LIMIT 0,10";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
 for ($j=0;$j<$res;$j++) {
  $csv_output .= $row[$j].", ";
 }
 $csv_output .= "\n";
}
*/

$filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());

$uploaddir = dirname(__FILE__) .'/csv/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.$filename.".".csv;

file_put_contents($uploadfile,$csv_output);

print $csv_output;

// Mail function and headers for file attachment
// can be implemented in this section afterwards

?>
```

As Mark Baker also stated, *"As the file hasn't been uploaded from a web browser but is being generated by your script on the server..."*, `move_uploaded_file()` is usually executed using a form along with other directives in order to `move` a created file into a folder/sub-folder.

Therefore, the use of `file_put_contents` is more suitable for this type of application because it will save to file and not upload, which is not what you need.

More information on both functions can be found on the PHP.net Website.

- [**file_put_contents**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)
- [**move_uploaded_file**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: @AmalMurali Thank you Amal, that's very much appreciated, cheers :) (I try to be as concise as possible)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to set these headers:

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv".date("Y-m-d").".csv");
header("Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
```

Because they let the client download the file and possibly save it on his harddisk. You want to save it on your server's harddisk.

You also do not need to move the uploaded file

```
move_uploaded_file($filename, $uploadfile);
```

because there is no file (to be) uploaded by the client.

The only thing to do is the following:

- grab the csv contents from the database;
- save them to a file (still server-side);

So here is the code:

```
$file = "export";
$csv_output .= "CustID,CustName,CustMobile,CustEmail\n";

$sql = "select CustID,CustName,CustMobile,CustEmail from dep_customer_details LIMIT 0,10";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < $res; $j++) {
        $csv_output .= $row[$j].", ";
    }
    $csv_output .= "\n";
}

$uploaddir = dirname(__FILE__)."/csv/";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.$filename;
file_put_contents($uploadfile, $csv_output); // Just like Mark Baker mentioned
```

Then you can read the file contents of the csv file and put them into the mail contents.

**But** since you only want to mail the CSV file, you can skip the whole process of storing the file on the server and reading it. That's because you can just put `$csv_output` somewhere in the mail contents.

How to do that, depends on how you are sending the mails (are you using PHPMailer, for example). See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) (and the comments!) for more details on how to do that.

I also suggest you search for tutorials on the subject.